# XOR Operator C++

Tags: c++, encryption, xor

Simple question here. Having a problem with the XOR operator (^). I can XOR integers fine and get the correct results; however, when XORing two chars, nothing is returned:

```
int main() {
    char a = 'a';
    char b = 'b';
    char c;

    c = a^b;
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

Nothing happens. No output. What am I doing wrong here. I'm trying to use this to XOR encrypt a string with a given key, but am having issues with this operation. I guess I could get the ASCII value and convert it to its corresponding char, but this tool will be used to encrypt files as well as plain text so I would like to avoid that at all costs.

Comment: You _are_ getting output, you merely cannot see it.

Comment: The result of that operation is `1`, and ASCII values below 32 or so are "unprintable".  One signifies the end of data, one is new line, one is carriage return, one is a beep...  See http://www.asciitable.com/  (I'm too lazy to make a good answer, someone else do it)

Comment: Just `std::cout << (int)c << '\n';` to see it.

Comment: Small tip: if you're using UNIX/Linux, piping output into `cat -vt` helps see non-printable characters, as they're replaced with a visible notation (in this case "^C").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::ostream::operator<<` (and `std::cout` is an `std::ostream`) outputs *formatted* text. When you pass it a `char`, it's trying to format and output a character (think ASCII). If the `char` isn't a printable character, it doesn't print it out (for obvious reasons). If you want it to output a formated *integer*, you need to cast it:

```
char a = 'a'; // 'a' == 0x61
char b = 'b'; // 'b' == 0x62
char c = a ^ b; // 0x61 ^ 0x62 == 0x03
std::cout << static_cast<int>(c) << std::endl;
```

For what it's worth, if you use the unformatted output function `std::ostream::write`, it will output unformatted characters. Beware, however, because if you try to write out an unprintable character, it will "work," but your console will not show it (because again, it's an unprintable character).

Comment: whats the difference in 'static_cast<int>(c)' and just '(int) c' or 'int(c)'?

Comment: @DavidHunt: `static_cast<>` does some checks to make sure the conversion is more-or-less safe, for example - you can't accidentally cast a `const T*` pointer to a `T*` (you'd have to use `const_cast<>`), or from an `int*` to a `double*` (you'd need `reinterpret_cast<>`).

Answer (score 5):

`'a' ^ 'b'` (`0x61 ^ 0x62`) results in `3`, which is a *non-printable character*, [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii) `ETX`, thus no printout.

Answer (score 2):

The result of `'a' ^ 'b'` is an unprintable character, namely `'\3'`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    char a = 'a';
    char b = 'b';
    char c;

    c = a^b;
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(c) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `std::cout << hex << c` won't work... [std::]`hex` applies to display of numbers and `c` is still treated as a character.  You'll need to cast `c` to a short/int/long....

Comment: Yep. That should teach me to compile and test before posting :)